# JSON parsing in windows phone 8

Tags: json, windows-phone-8

i am new to windows phone development and so by references implemented some code but i am not able to get the desired result.

i want to parse a JSON that is received as a response from the server. 
Please find below my code.

```
 class JSONParsing
    {
        public Status response { get; set; }
        public static void webClient1_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Result))
            {
                try
                {

                    JSONParsing root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONParsing>(e.Result);
                    // root is null here

                    JObject obj = root.response.statusDetail;
                    // from here it goes to Catch block
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> pair in obj)
                    {
                        string key = pair.Key;
                        foreach (JObject detail in pair.Value as JArray)
                        {
                            string Code = detail["Code"].ToString();
                            string Msg = detail["Msg"].ToString();
                            string RegistrationID = detail["RegistrationID"].ToString();
                            string Name = detail["Name"].ToString();
                            string Phone = detail["Phone"].ToString();
                            string email = detail["email"].ToString();
                            string password = detail["password"].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Cause of Exception is " + ex.Message);

                   // exception is-- "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
                }
            } // if for empty
        }

    }

    public class Status
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Msg { get; set; }
        public object RegistrationID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("")]
        public JObject statusDetail { get; set; }
    }
    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Status> Status { get; set; }
        public int success { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Please Help.

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem. "*I am not able to get the desired result*", doesn't add much info. What is your desired result, and what result you get from current code?. please, at least provide sample jason string you got.

Answer (score 0):

If root is null the class 'JSONParsing'  is not having same class structure as the json

and since root is null, accessing property inside a null('root.response.statusDetail') will throw an exception

you can use http://json2csharp.com/ to get the class structure of the json